# Docker Issue - (code exited, status=1/Failure)

Tags: postgresql, docker

The problem is, i've installed Docker in my pc.
Tried to make a Postgres container as the docs says.

The big problem that begun with my headache was that i started the container and the container exit with the code(1).
So i tried to seach a lot of "Solutions" in so much sites and any of them resolved that problem.

#### OS:

```
    Deppin 15.11
```

#### Problem Terminal Report:

```
    Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript docker, action "start" failed.
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d
           └─hosts.conf, override.conf
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2020-04-25 13:12:26 -03; 18ms ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
  Process: 10333 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// -H tcp://127.0.0.1:2375 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 10333 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
      CPU: 80ms
```

#### JOURNALCTL -XE:

```
root@usuario-PC:/home/usuario# journalctl -xe
-- A unidade docker.service falhou.
-- 
-- O resultado é failed.
mai 08 11:00:16 usuario-PC systemd[1]: docker.socket: Unit entered failed state.
mai 08 11:00:16 usuario-PC systemd[1]: docker.service: Unit entered failed state.
mai 08 11:00:16 usuario-PC systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
mai 08 11:00:42 usuario-PC systemd[1]: Starting Laptop Mode Tools - Battery Polling Service...
-- Subject: Unidade lmt-poll.service sendo iniciado
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- A unidade lmt-poll.service está sendo iniciada.
mai 08 11:00:42 usuario-PC systemd[1]: Reloading Laptop Mode Tools.
-- Subject: Unidade laptop-mode.service iniciou recarregamento de sua configuração
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- A unidade laptop-mode.service iniciou o recarregamento de sua configuração.
mai 08 11:00:42 usuario-PC systemd[1]: Started Laptop Mode Tools - Battery Polling Service.
-- Subject: Unidade lmt-poll.service concluiu a inicialização
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- A unidade lmt-poll.service concluiu a inicialização.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
mai 08 11:00:42 usuario-PC laptop_mode[11704]: Laptop mode
mai 08 11:00:42 usuario-PC laptop_mode[11704]: enabled, not active [unchanged]
mai 08 11:00:42 usuario-PC systemd[1]: Reloaded Laptop Mode Tools.
-- Subject: Unidade laptop-mode.service concluiu recarregamento de sua configuração
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- A unidade laptop-mode.service concluiu o recarregamento de sua configuração.
-- 
-- O resultado é done.
```

Comment: I think your problem happens before you run any containers. Your Docker service can't start. Are you using any VPN or something else that can conflict with Docker's bridge IP configurations?

Comment: No, i don't use any VPN. But when i make a container 1 sec after it quit with the code 1.

Comment: Can you edit your question with some more descriptive logs from `sudo journalctl -xe` after the problem occurs? To see what causes Docker to fail.

Comment: sure, the journalctl is already there now

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is to make sure your docker service is running?

```
$ sudo systemctl status docker
```

The second thing you need to restart your docker service. I think it will be work.

```
$ sudo systemctl restart docker
```

And the final thing, if all of above it's not working then you can restart your computer (haha)